# Too many connection in java jdbc

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

Error:- SEVERE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections" 
code is shown below

```
   try {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String line;
        String tru="TRUNCATE `project`.`uploadtable`;";
        try
       {
             Statement stmt = Dutil.getConnection().createStatement();



     stmt.executeUpdate(tru);
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        try {
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                String values[]=line.split("\t");
                String[] splitStr = values[1].split(" ");


               try {String  sql="INSERT INTO `project`.`uploadtable` 
            (`empid`, `date`, `time`, `in_out_index`) VALUES 
            ('"+values[0]+"', '"+splitStr[0]+"', '"+splitStr[1]+"', 
             '"+values[3]+"');";
                    PreparedStatement 
                   pst=Dutil.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
                    pst.executeUpdate();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error");

             Logger.getLogger(UploadFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
              null, ex);
                }
            } br.close();

             this.dispose();
           LogButtonFrame lbf=new LogButtonFrame();
          lbf.clockinouttable();
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Upload Complete");} catch 
           (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UploadFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
          null, ex);
            }
             } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(UploadFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
            null, ex);
          }
          catch (Exception ex) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
        }
```

Comment: please post your code don't use images

Comment: You need to close statements and connections after you've used them, otherwise they will remain open and at some point you'll get this error. See: [Processing SQL Statements with JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is:

```
PreparedStatement pst = Dutil.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
```

You haven't shown the code of `Dutil`, but assuming it creates a new connection on each call, this means the connection is not getting closed, leaving it to luck, driver implementation specifics, and the garbage collector to get it closed.

Instead you should use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
try (Connection connection = Dutil.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    // Use pst
}
```

After the end of this block, both `pst` and `connection` will be properly closed, even if exceptions occur, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be creating connections and never closing them, although its hard to tell from the images you've posed.

Comment: where do i close the connection?

Comment: Where you do your INSERT statement. You should look at using `try / catch / finally` or `try with resources`. There are a lot of examples on the internet and I would imagine the link that Jesper added in the comment to your question would cover it in good detail

Answer (score 0):

If your application requires more than one connection, you should use a connection pool like the Apache DB connection pool where you can configure number of connections. Here is the link for DBCP documentation https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/

If you are sure your application only needs one connection, make your connection object as a Singleton object in DBUtil class. This will definitely solve the issue and no need to close the connection. Your entire application will make use of single connection object to connect to DB.